# Codeacademy - a night at the movies (ruby). Enabling the user to find movies without being case sensitive

Tags: ruby

I've just completed the Ruby CodeAcademy task, 'night at the movies' (code below).

When searching for existing movies in the database, I want the user to be able to input the title (in this case only StarWars or Divergent) without it having to be case sensitive? At the moment a search of 'starwars' returns an error (as opposed to StarWars which doesn't)!

Thanks

```
movies = {
  StarWars: 4.8, 
  Divergent: 4.7
  }

puts "What would you like to do? "

choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
  puts "What movie would you like to add? "
  title = gets.chomp.downcase
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil? 
    puts "What rating does the movie have? "
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end

when "update"
  puts "Please enter movie title."
  title = gets.chomp.to_sym
  if movies[title].nil?
    puts "This title doesn't exist!"
  else 
    puts "what's the new rating for this movie (0 to 4)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been updated with a rating of 
#{rating}."
  end

when "display"
  movies.each do |movies, rating|
    puts "#{movies}: #{rating}"
  end

when "delete"
  puts "Please enter movie title:"
  title = gets.chomp.to_sym
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "Title doesn't exist"
  else
  movies.delete(title)
  puts "#{title} has been deleted!"
end

else
  puts "Error!"
end
```

Comment: "returns an error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the error message?

Comment: Well, you have a key `:StarWars` and you don't have a key `:starwars`. It only makes sense that searching for `:startwars` wouldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lowercase symbols

```
movies = { starwars: 4.8, divergent: 4.7}
```

and then turn the users input into all lowercase letters

```
  title = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
```

this would turn any variance in capitalization of the titles (`STARwars`, `StARwarS`, ect...) into `starwars`

Comment: Thanks all. John Ingram, I tried .downcase without altering the symbols to downcase too, which didn’t work. I giess